# How to get filename last photo in Swift 2.0 iOS9?

Tags: image, uiimage, filenames, photo-gallery

I want to get `file_name (example = IMG_xxxx.jpg)`

```
func lastphoto() {
   var fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
          fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

    var fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions)

    if (fetchResult.lastObject != nil) {

        var lastAsset: PHAsset = fetchResult.lastObject as! PHAsset
        let options:PHImageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersion.Current

        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(lastAsset, 
                        targetSize: self.imageView.bounds.size, 
                        contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, 
                        options: PHImageRequestOptions(), 
                        resultHandler: { (result, info) -> Void in
                                self.imageView.image = result
                                let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
                                let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: nil)
                        })


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 9.0, you can get the original file name using the following:

```
var filename: String?

if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResourcesForAsset(lastAsset)
    if let resource = resources.first {
        filename = resource.originalFilename
    }
}
```

If you're supporting pre-iOS 9.0 versions, you can also try using an undocumented workaround that still works as of iOS 9.1:

```
filename = lastAsset.valueForKey("filename") as? String
```

Comment: is possible change this filename or save a photo with a custom filename?